# Is it possible to de-activate a pinmux function/group via kernel's debugfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

It's known that writing group/function names to `/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/<controller>/pinmux-select` can enable a pinmux function/group on the fly.

Is there a way to do the opposite, i.e. de-activate a pinmux function/group on the fly via debugfs?

Comment: What do you mean by "deactivating"? There is no such thing, you can switch functions to whatever one which internal mux has capability for. Often, GPIO is Function 0, main function of the pin is under Function 1, auxiliary one at Function 2 and so on...

Comment: @0andriy By "de-activating", I meant to unclaim the related pins (in the group/function) from pinctrl driver. What I did so far is to update the DTS to disable the device which uses the group/function, thus after reboot, the related pins are UNCLAIMED. Probably to disable the corresponding device driver (somehow) on the fly can achieve the same effect.

Comment: I do not understand you. The hardware can't "unclaim" pins, it's a pure software feature if exists. So, you want to drop any grouping of a certain pin subset (*"group*")?

Comment: Suppose pinctrl driver manages one pin (P) which is muxed into two functions/groups (A and B). A properly implemented pinctrl driver makes sure the following will not happen: A and B function are both enable at the same time. Support that in DTS, A is enabled, B is disabled, so by default, P is CLAIMED (by function A), thus it can not be claimed by B at the same time. In my scenario, A is SD, B is gpio. What I wanted is to manually manipulate the pin as GPIO by "gpio exporting" the pin to sysfs. As long as the pin is claimed by function A, I am not able to gpio exporting the pin.

Comment: So I was wondering, if there is a similar way to manually de-activate function A (via sysfs, e.g.), thus the pin is no longer claimed by function A, so it can be claimed by function B as a GPIO pin. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Yes, you simply unload the consumer of A and then you free to use the pin(s) for B or elsewhere.